# How to make website (non-unique) visitor counter with text only

Tags: php

I would like to have a counter of times my website was visited, but non-unique so it can count even if the user has already visited it, I would like it to appear as a text or string in my index.html page

would like it to appear in that html code below, I already have a counter.txt file using php to do the work, but it shows it as an image and I want just simple text

//html

```
<div>
<p> <center> Number of visitors:</center> </p>
<center><img alt="Visitor counter" src="counter.php" /></center>
</div>
```

//php

```
<?php
session_start();
$counter_name = "counter.txt";

// Check if a text file exists.
//If not create one and initialize it to zero.
if (!file_exists($counter_name)) {
    $f = fopen($counter_name, "w");
    fwrite($f,"0");
    fclose($f);
}
// Read the current value of our counter file
$f = fopen($counter_name,"r");
$counterVal = fread($f, filesize($counter_name));
fclose($f);

// Has visitor been counted in this session?
// If not, increase counter value by one
if(!isset($_SESSION['hasVisited'])){
    $_SESSION['hasVisited']="yes";
    $counterVal++;
    $f = fopen($counter_name, "w");
    fwrite($f, $counterVal);
    fclose($f);
}

$counterVal = str_pad($counterVal, 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
$chars = preg_split('//', $counterVal);
$im = imagecreatefrompng("canvas.png");

$src1 = imagecreatefrompng ("digits/$chars[1].png");
$src2 = imagecreatefrompng ("digits/$chars[2].png");
$src3 = imagecreatefrompng ("digits/$chars[3].png");
$src4 = imagecreatefrompng ("digits/$chars[4].png");
$src5 = imagecreatefrompng ("digits/$chars[5].png");

imagecopymerge($im, $src1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 56, 76, 100);
imagecopymerge($im, $src2, 60, 0, 0, 0, 56, 76, 100);
imagecopymerge($im, $src3, 120, 0, 0, 0, 56, 76, 100);
imagecopymerge($im, $src4, 180, 0, 0, 0, 56, 76, 100);
imagecopymerge($im, $src5, 240, 0, 0, 0, 56, 76, 100);

// Output and free from memory
header('Content-Type: image/png');
echo imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Comment: Did you try anything yet? How'd that go?

Comment: css, html or javascript has nothing to do with a server side counter, unless it is about refresh and styling at screen

Comment: you should use a database. like firebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simple text file holding the visitor counter can do that,

```
<?php

function visitor_counter():int{
    static $cache=null;
    if($cache!==null){
        return $cache;
    }
    $fp=fopen("index.visitor_counter.txt","c+b");
    flock($fp,LOCK_EX);
    $cache=(int)stream_get_contents($fp);
    ++$cache;
    rewind($fp);
    fwrite($fp,(string)$cache);
    flock($fp,LOCK_UN);
    fclose($fp);
    return $cache;
}
```

then just call visitor_counter() inside your index file.

if you're wondering why i'm bothering with flock() instead of a simple file_get_contents(), it's because a race condition can occur if several people visit your site at once, for example if the counter is at 100 and 2 people visit at the same time, 2 different php instances read `100` from the file, and increase it to `101`, and write `101` back to the harddrive twice, in that case the text file would contain the incorrect number `101` instead of the correct number `102`, but flock() here makes sure that won't happen, by making php instance #2 wait until instance #1 has read and updated the file (#2 will wait from #1 does LOCK_EX to #1 does LOCK_UN before #2 does the exact same thing~).

here is a simple-to-understand, but bugged (prone to the above race condition) implementation:

```
function visitor_counter():int{
    $visitors=(int)file_get_contents("index.visitor_counter.txt");
    ++$visitors;
    file_put_contents("index.visitor_counter.txt",(string)$vistors);
    return $vistors;
}
```

(DO NOT use the last implementation, it's bugged.)